# Ghost Script Not Working isn;t working, how should I fix it?

Tags: php, ghostscript, imagick

I keep trying to run this block of code where it takes a PDF and then turns it into images
   `$pdfFilePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name']; $imagick = new \Imagick(); $imagick->setOption('gswin64c.exe','C:\Program Files\gs\gs10.02.1\bin\gswin64c.exe'); $imagick->readImage($pdfFilePath);`
When I get to this line
`$imagick->readImage($pdfFilePath);`

It returns with this error
`Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: FailedToExecuteCommand` "gs" -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r72x72" -dPrinted=false "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/*replaced*/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-8eSF0JRObHf25L8_hRwG86o77IeILqcQ%d" "-fC:/Users/*replaced*/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-9Uj4dmKzR7AI0hXLFmPFF2WflhBeMaFo" "-fC:/Users/*replaced*/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-TTHCpuykEPwnm7xV6VgHIlOs4PaVHi6-"' (The system cannot find the file specified. ) @ error/delegate.c/ExternalDelegateCommand/516 in C:\Xampp2\htdocs\Website\main.php:8 Stack trace: #0 C:\Xampp2\htdocs\Website\main.php(8): Imagick->readImage('C:\Xampp2\tmp\p...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\Xampp2\htdocs\Website\main.php on line 8`

I don't really know what it is saying, but I do know it is having some issue in finding the file!
Thanks In Advance!

I tried many things like reinstalling Ghost Script, Imagick, XAMPP, and tried to find other solutions online but it didn't render much result.

Comment: On Windows, the Ghostscript executable is not called **gs** and that (if you actually read the error) is what ImageMagick says it failed to execute. Hardly surprising, since it is trying to execute the wrong thing. If you want to use Ghostscript with ImageMagick then you need to configure ImageMagick to look for one of; gswin32, gswin32c, gswin64 or gswin64c (depending on the word size). And no, I can't tell you how to configure ImageMagick. As KJ says, just use Ghostscript directly, using ImageMagick just complicates things.